# Want to SSH from external IP. Tried with different router at different network but failed

Tags: linux, router, ssh, ip, port-forwarding

I simply want to SSH into my local host from outside. This is my router where I am applying the port forward.

```
Manufacturer:Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd;
ProductClass:HG8245H;
SerialNumber:485754432ED3A492;
IP:10.0.0.1; << This is my gateway ip.
My Host IP: 10.0.0.95
```

I can get my external IP via curl ifconfig.me using the terminal in ubuntu.

What I did is simply port forward within the router.

```
Internal port:22 >> port for SSH
External port:22
```

What I am doing is now inputting the below command within router

```
ssh -p 22 myuser@my-external-IP
```

The respond is just nothing and after waiting long I just have to forcefully cancel it.

Any idea what is wrong. I have tried with multiple other network and different router but still, it never works. I am stuck with this for more than a Week. There are multiple answer and solutions to this problem and I've followed mostly every possible way but still failed to achieve.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you actually _testing_ this from outside?

Comment: Exactly, I am testing it from my public IP as mentioned above. I can easily SSH locally into any of my machines but I fail to SSH from another network into my machines.

Comment: Testing with the public IP within the same network and from outside as asked in the first comment is not the same thing.

Comment: @MichaelBay I exactly know what you are highlighting. What I do is I note my public IP when I'm within LAN. Now, I am SSHing using my public IP from LAN and it should access my machine, but it doesn't. Secondly, I have changed my network to some other (4G) and now trying to SSH into my local using that IP which i noted down. But still doesn't work. Hope you get what I did.

Answer (score 0):

22 might be filtered by your ISP to prevent people from hacking their customers. Try setting External port to something like 2022, 10022(above 1024) and see if that works. Also on the Port forwarding setting you should provide the internal ip address to which to forward together with the port.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have tried using few IPs above 1024 like 2244, 2525 but still no result. Besides that, I am mentioning my local machine host IP (internal IP) into the router which is **10.0.0.95** as mentioned above but still, I am failing to access it. As mentioned, I have tried every possible way, but I can't figure out where am I lacking.